# How do I loop though an array in a `this.state` object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `GET` request fetching data, the data contains an `object` and then an `array` in the `object`. Then, I use `this.setState` and now have an `array`, in an `object`, in an `object`

The problem is, when I try to loop through the array, I cannot, as I get a

`TypeError: this.state.games.games is undefined`

If I only have `this.state.games`, and try to loop through I get a

`TypeError: this.state.games.forEach is not a function`

I have resolved this by a `try...catch` method however I feel that this is not the best way of going about this.

```js
class HomePage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {games: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost.com:5000/user/games`, {withCredentials: true})
            .then(res => {
                const games = res.data;
                this.setState({ games })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const games = [];

        try {
            this.state.games.games.forEach(function (game, index) {
                console.log(index) // index
                console.log(game) // value

                games.push(
                    <Grid.Column>
                        <MyGames key={index} game={{title: game.title, description: game.genre, thumbnail: game.thumbnail}}/>
                    </Grid.Column>
                )

            })
        }
        catch( e ) {
            console.log("Error: " + e );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Grid columns={1}>

                    <Grid.Column>
                        <FriendsList/>

                        <Header as='h3'>My Games</Header>
                        <Grid columns={4} container={'true'} padded>
                                {games}
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid.Column>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

In the end, I am trying to loop through the data received from the endpoint and loop through each index and display their attributes.

**UPDATE:**
The issue was with `const game = res.data`, because this was an object, it was causing the issue with the object in an object. Changing it to `res.data.games` fixed the issue as `.games` is the array in the data given.

Comment: What is `res.data` ? Probably not an array?

Comment: @JonasWilms Yes, you are right! It was an object so I just changed it to `res.data.games` and it worked! Thanks to @JLRishe for explaining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to loop through `this.state.games.games`, but in your constructor, the initial value you give to `state` is `{ games: [] }`. Therefore, `this.state.games.games` is not an array initially and this is why you are getting an error.

Two ways to fix.

Initialize your state to a structure that reflects the way you are accessing the state:

```
this.state = { games: { games: [] } };
```

Or, probably a better idea, change your code so that your array is `this.state.games` rather than `this.state.games.games`:

```
.then(res => {
    const games = res.data.games;
    this.setState({ games })
})

// further below ...

this.state.games.forEach(function (game, index) {
```

Comment: you need to understand what OP is asking BEFORE posting an answer

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano I understand what OP is asking and I see what's wrong with their code. That's why I posted an answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean to be rude to you. the problem is what inside `res.data` like jonas commented before.

Comment: @JLRishe Ahh!! I should of see that! It works now, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

you are making ajax call,which is async ,you trying to use games from state before your ajax call finish ,hence its causing an error

```
  //your render method 
render() {
    const games = [];
      if(this.state.games.games.length<=0){
       return <h1>Please wait while loading data</h1>
      }
    try {
        this.state.games.games.forEach(function (game, index) {
            console.log(index) // index
            console.log(game) // value

            games.push(
                <Grid.Column>
                    <MyGames key={index} game={{title: game.title, description: game.genre, thumbnail: game.thumbnail}}/>
                </Grid.Column>
            )

        })
    }
    catch( e ) {
        console.log("Error: " + e );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid columns={1}>

                <Grid.Column>
                    <FriendsList/>

                    <Header as='h3'>My Games</Header>
                    <Grid columns={4} container={'true'} padded>
                            {games}
                    </Grid>
                </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}
```

till the time your data loaded from server ,you can show some animation 
instead plain message,

Comment: That's more a comment than an answer. A solution with code would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
        this.state.games.games.forEach(function (game, index) {

        })
```

to

```
        this.state.games.forEach(function (game, index){

        })
```